# I dont press enter but ReadLine() says I did

Tags: c#, integer, console-application

Fixed, but now it automatically presses enter when it gets to the `Main();` thing and I can't actually input anything in time. Anyone know what's wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Bruh
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int pog = 0;
            int pog2 = 0;
            Random r = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("Input a whole number");
            string poggers = Console.ReadLine();
            if (int.TryParse(poggers, out pog))
            {
                pog = int.Parse(poggers);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Not a number. Please input a number and not letters.");
                Console.Read();
                System.Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Input a number higher than the previous");
            string poggers2 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (int.TryParse(poggers2, out pog2))
            {
                pog2 = int.Parse(poggers2);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Not a number. Please input a number and not letters.");
                Console.Read();
                System.Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            int genRand = r.Next(pog, pog2);
            Console.WriteLine("This number was randomly generated between " + pog + " and " + pog2 + " and we got: " + genRand);
            Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to try again? Y/N");
            ConsoleKeyInfo answer = Console.ReadKey();
            if (answer.KeyChar == 'y' || answer.KeyChar == 'Y')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Main();
            }
            else if (answer.KeyChar == 'n' || answer.KeyChar == 'N')
            {
                System.Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Y/N not any other character");
                Console.Read();
                System.Environment.Exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us which line line 29 is?

Comment: `int.TryParse()` return a `bool`, not an `int`. You don't need the `if (poggers2.All(char.IsDigit))` check. Just use `if (int.TryParse(poggers2, out pog2))` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help @41686d6564 , I changed it and now it works.. except everytime I run it the loop i made runs once then i get the error message i programmed in
`ERROR: Not a number. Please input a number and not letters.` even if i havent even input a number yet. is there something about inputs and doing `Main();` that breaks it?

Comment: btw this is what happens when you run it
`Input a whole number
1
Input a number higher than the previous
10
This number was randomly generated between 1 and 10 and we got: 3

Would you like to try again? Y/N
y

Input a whole number
ERROR: Not a number. Please input a number and not letters.` sorry i dont know how or if i can do multiple lines so it looks weird

Comment: Sorry I'm new I don't know what I just did but now you cant answer and can only comment sorry

Answer (score 1):

Dont assign the value of `int.TryParse(poggers2, out pog2)` to `pog2`. because `pog2` is `int`. and `int.tryParse` returns `bool`.

And as suggested by user @ 41686d6564, you don't need this check `poggers2.All(char.IsDigit)`.

Answer (score 1):

You use `TryParse()`, in line 29, not plain `Parse()`.

**Parse()**

Returns value directly, but throws an exception, if input isn't valid (the string can't be parsed to the wanted type).

**TryParse()**

This will not throw an exception, but just return *false* if the string vould not be parsed. The parsed value will be returned thru the variable given by the **out** mark, if you got a **true** return.

```
int result;

// This will throw an exception
result = int.Parse("Hello");

// This will just return false
if (int.TryParse("Hello", out result)
    Debug.WriteLine("Result now has a valid int value!");
else
    Debug.WriteLine("Sorry, could not parse the text");
```

When using `TryParse`, you make the code more readable and do not need to verify the string, before parsing (`poggers2.All(char.IsDigit)`.